# Customize Linux WAagent for VM extensions

Tags: azure

We want to host an image on Azure marketplace but it will be a closed VM. I dont want any user to run any script or install any software using Azure VM extensions, thus want to disable the extensions.

Is there any way I can disable the extension ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using a weird approach. This is essentially a SaaS, but you plan to distribute it as IaaS.

Even if you kill waagent after VM provision nothing prevent user from using mounting your VHD to another VM and do whatever he wants. So you should really aim at SaaS\PaaS approach

Comment: We do not want to open OS disk and as far as I know user can't detach OS disk and mount it on other machine. I don't care about the data disk.

Comment: they can. they can clone the disk and attach it. or just shutdown the vm

Comment: Anyway, that is the different case. Currently, can you let me know what we can do to disable extension. Is it possible without disabling waagent ?

Comment: no, there is no way of doing that. i mean in others person subscription